# first and last chilld

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has 5 divs in it. Here are pictures of it:

**product-div (1280px)**
[image]

**product-pc (5 div, inside product-div. 1 div size is 252px)**
[image]

I want to center these 5 div in the parent one.
My Calculations are the following:

```
product-div  1280px
product-pc  252px
252*5 = 1260px

now i have 20px

20/4 = 5px
5/2 = 2.5
```

As a result want to use `margin-left 2.5px` and `margin right 2.5px`,
except for the first child where i want `margin-left : 0px` and for the last child `margin-right : 0px`
I can't get this to work, what am i doing wrong?

```css
.product-div {
    display: flex;
    width: 1280px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

product-div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

product-div:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.product-pc {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: grey;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-div">
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try: `.product-div:first-child, .product-div:last-child {margin:0}` and do not forget the dot in front of the class name :)

Comment: thank you. i try this also, but not working.

Comment: Please add html code also.

Comment: I added html code

Comment: i guess you were selecting the wrong element, try instead `.product-pc:first-child, .product-pc:last-child {margin:0}` wile`.product-div`is a single parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, I think your child class is product-pc so you need to add this class instead of product-div. Another thing is, you have used margin for first child and padding for last. I have added the margin for both so you can use anything as per your requirement.

```css
.product-pc:first-child{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.product-pc:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the period in your css `.`

```
  .product-div .product-pc:first-child {
       margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .product-div .product-pc:last-child {
       margin-right: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct selector.

```
.product-pc:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
}
.product-pc:last-child { 
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

What is wrong in your code:

```
product-div:first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting a parent div which don't have a child. Please select the first div of the Parent and then use the first and last child.

As in List we do this

```
ul li:first-child {}
```

So try this

```
.product-div .product-pc:first-child {margin-left: 0px;}
.product-div .product-pc:last-child {margin-right: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead a little bit differently to achieve that space. Instead of selecting the first and last child, I would select a `.product-pc` that is followed by a `.product-pc` and give that one the double amount of left-margin (5px in this case, instead of 2.5px). That means that all .product-pcs except the first get a left margin.

I added a grey background to better showcase the solution.

Less code.

No strange half pixels.

```css
.product-div{
    display: flex;
    width: 1280px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.product-pc + .product-pc {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.product-pc{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: grey;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-div">
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-pc">
      <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="product-name">Pixel 2 XL</p>
      <div>
          <a class="product-price" href="#">500₾</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your first and last `product-pc` to stick to the side.

That can be done by adding a `justify-content: space-between` to your `product-pc` container.

Like so,

```
.product-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1280px;
}
```

By the way, it's not good practice to set fix width for elements. If I were you, I would change that `width: 1280px;` to use `%` or `vw`. like this: `width: 90vw`.